# Solr:WordDelimiterFilterFactory for substrings of a camelcase word

Tags: solr, autocomplete, substring, camelcasing

I want to implement an Autocomplete-feature with Solr that work for source code identifiers in CamelCase. I use an `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` together with `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` to split CamelCase words:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_autocomplete" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="100" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The id `isSlowTraceEnabled` will get split into `isTraceEnabled`, `is`, `Slow`, `Trace` and `Enabled` from the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`.

But I also want to index the words `SlowTrace`, `SlowTraceEnabled` and `TraceEnabled` so that the user can search for only parts of the CamelCase word. **Is there any filter that produces these substrings from a CamelCase word?**

(I found one similar problem in the Lucene in action book, 2nd edition, p. 388 in the Case study of Krugle. But the solution is quite complicated and I just need to search for about 1000 IDs and not so many IDs as in Krugle.)

Comment: What does the data look like in the index now?  It would be easier to solve if you could demonstrate what is wrong with it.  Also, what are you trying to accomplish with the `EdgeNGramFilter`?

Comment: I use the `EdgeNGramFilter` to implement the Autocomplete-feature like in [this tutorial](http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/). With the current solution the user could search the ID `isTraceEnabled` with `isTra` or `Trac` but not with "sub-words" in the CamelCase word like `TraceE` or `SlowTr`.